# How can I equivalent the same sql by collection addFilter

Tags: collection

My Sql is Below :

```
SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `tab` AS `main_table` WHERE (`main_table`.`list_id` = '36') AND (`active` = '1') AND (`start_datetime` <= '2017-02-14 09:13:58')  OR main_table.debug = 1
```

I know use by

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter('list_id', 36)
       ->addFieldToFilter('start_datetime', '2017-02-14 09:13:58')
       ;
```

to equivalent WHERE (`main_table`.`list_id` = '36') AND (`active` = '1') AND (`start_datetime` <= '2017-02-14 09:13:58')

But How can I do to equivalent

```
      OR main_table.debug = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for SQL query equivalent to your collection with filter then `printLogQuery` function will work for you.

```
 $collection->addFieldToFilter('list_id', 36)
   ->addFieldToFilter('start_datetime', '2017-02-14 09:13:58');
```

`$collection->printLogQuery(true);` OR `$collection->getSelect()->__toString();`

Above code will give you the complete SQL query equivalent to your collection